# How to use a node.js back-end server to interact with the front-end and a mongolab database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web, mlab

I am building a website with a simple jquery/html/css front-end and a node.js server back-end. If my front-end has a function to request a user's information from the server like so:

```
function requestUser(email, password) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8888/getUser/" + email + "/" + password, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and my node server looks like this:

```
var http = require("http"),
    mongojs = require("mongojs"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    url = require("url");
    express = require("express")
var server = http.createServer(requestHandler);
server.listen(8888);
var uri = "mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds036698.mongolab.com:36698/alirodatabase";
var db = mongojs(uri, ["Papers", "Users"]);
console.log("node server running back end of app");
function requestHandler(request, response) {
    //request for user is .../getUser/<username>/<password>
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var details = path.split('/');
    if(details.indexOf("getUser") != -1) {
        console.log("recieved request for user");
        var user = db.Users.find({"email": details[details.indexOf("getUser") + 1],
                                  "password": details[details.indexOf("getUser") + 2]});
        user = user.toArray[0];
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/json"});
        response.write(JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    else {
        fs.readFile("./index.html", function(err, file) {
            if(err) {
                return 
            }
            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            response.end(file, "utf-8");
        });
    }
}
```

why isn't it working? I get a 'mixed content' and/or 'corss-origin' error from firefox when I try to request from the server. How can I have the node server running in the same domain as the rest of the site to avoid these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is really hard to read your code, I understand what you are trying to do, but let me suggest first a better structure easier to read, understand and implement more routes for your server, please check here:

```
var express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/getUser/:user/:passwd', function(req, res, next) {
  // Perform all mongo operations here using req.params.user and req.params.passwd
  // and in the callback send a response like the object below
  res.json({
    msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!',
    user: req.params.user,
    passwd: req.params.passwd
  });
});

app.listen(8888, function() {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 8888');
});
```

Also the lack of CORS support (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) as you will need this in your use case for if you are planning to host serve static files consuming this service hosted in a different server, so lets use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors and it will allow express to process a request from anywhere.